# Dirt or concrete for Aluminum fence posts?

Tags: concrete, fence, post, aluminum

Should I use concrete, dirt, or gravel to set aluminum fence post is disturbed soil?  The soil was backfilled 9 months ago, and it may not be fully settled.

Answer (score 5):

### Do not use concrete.

[Concrete and aluminum have incompatible issues.](https://www.concreteconstruction.net/concrete-production-precast/how-does-contact-with-aluminum-affect-concrete_o)

Dirt and compact it well, every 2" or so as you refill the hole.