# Sufficient Concrete Thickness for Table?

Tags: concrete, cement, countertops, concrete-block, engineering

I'm planning on making a Concrete patio table. My plan is to make a 6ft x 3ft Concrete top. The frame will be 4 legs. I will have 3 aluminum angles running vertically underneath the length of the table for support spaced 8 inches apart. There will be 6 inch overhang by the concrete top on each side. The top will be 1.25inch thick steel wire reinforced concrete rated 5000psi. My question is, will the Thickness of the table be sufficient to hold a person leaning on the edge of the overhang or does it need to be thicker? I don't want someone to lean over on the 6in overhang and crack or break it.

Comment: Hoping that somebody with engineering skill will chime in, but I can’t imagine that 1-1/4” will be sufficient for even the top (not to mention the overhang) without a drastic underwire structure.

Comment: Aluminum + concrete is a *very bad combination* https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/193661/18078

Comment: How thick are these aluminum angles?  I have a hard time envisioning aluminum angles actually doing anything against the weight of your concrete top.  What is the diameter of the ww mesh?

Comment: Have you seen the plans and a finished product? My counters that I did in white concrete and we’re well supported and reinforced were a bit thicker, 3” angle over 6’ would worry me steel would probably be strong enough, I would be concerned that aluminum will sag and flex with that weight and 1-1/4 is not very thick.

Comment: Thanks everyone. After some research I think I will change up the design a little. So looks like the consensus is that the steel bars are not enough for the concrete. So it was suggested to me that I make the table out of wood (most likely 3/4 in melamine ) and then put a thin layer (maybe 1/2 inch) of concrete on top. This way it will give it additional support, give me the concrete top I'm looking for, and keep the weight under control. The legs I will keep as metal because I like the look but the support for the top I can probably make out of wood 2x4s. Let me know your thoughts on this.