Connecting two Aluminium post together
I have aluminum fencing post of 7 ft. Because of less height, I cant use this to insert directly into the concrete to have additional stability and strength. One option is directly installed on a concrete base with screws but that doesn't seems to be strong as sometimes we get wind of 60-70 km/h plus I am in snowy region so frost lines is another thing to worry about.
One another option I am thinking about is using an additional 2-3 ft extra aluminium similar post and adding it on top of 7 ft of aluminum post to make it as 10FT post total and inserting 3 ft directly into concrete to have additional strength.
How should I attach two post together strongly so that it can withstand wind and lateral pressure.
This is the post- https://www.rona.ca/en/product/everhome-6-ft-surface-mount-post-for-composite-fence-lwpst0001-332005780?viewStore=82413&cq_src=google_ads&cq_cmp=19750304322&cq_con=&cq_term=&cq_med=pla&cq_plac=&cq_net=x&cq_pos=&cq_plt=gp&&cm_mmc=paid_search-_-google-_-aw_pmax_generic_Online+Exclusive-_-&gad_source=1&gclid=CjwKCAjw9IayBhBJEiwAVuc3fvY8tF6x-XSyuTAAwyy-LmUpiSRfl4azLEjfJ41OtBuTmMLLUtqRbhoCejAQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds

Aluminum posts in concrete are a corrosion disaster that does not wait long to happen. See: https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/193661/18078 among others.

Thats intersting..didnt know Aluminium and Concerete doesnt go well..I see lot of installation like that where they just insert post all the way inside the concrete

Looking at the manufacturer's installation instructions and they have no problem recommending concrete for in-ground installation

Those posts are only 6ft long and are designed to be surface mounted to concrete footings. You need to buy the 8ft version which is designed to be in-ground inserted into concrete as per the manufacturer's directions. They say to bury it 30 inches so you will have a fence height of 5 1/2 feet.


I have purchased already 7 ft in height post. The link was just to show what kind of post I am talking about...If I put directly into the concrete for 2.5 ft, I just get only 4.5 ft of fence which is not enough, that's why I am thinking about attaching two posts together(not sure the way hence the question), 7 ft original post + 3 ft addition to it and insert 3 ft all the way to the concrete....so that I can get 7 ft of fence height....Problem is I am not sure how to attach two aluminum post together.
